# How to make use of upper level values in Handlebars templates

Tags: handlebars.js, template-engine

Hi I have following data and template to make sue with handlebars. Now I want to make use of "count"   `<small>{{{count}}}</small>` in loop. How I can make use of this.

```
var items = {
    "count": 3,
    "value": {
        "title": "Daily Feeds Mashup",
        "description": "Feeds Description",
        "items": [
            {
                 "title": "Title One",
                 "link": "http://linkone.com",

            },
            {
                 "title": "Title Two",
                 "link": "http://titletwo.com",
                 "description": "Title two description"
            },
            {
                 "title": "Title Three",
                 "link": "http://linkone.com",           
            }
        ]
    }
}

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="itemTemplate">
                <ul data-role="listview" id="posts">
                    {{#each items}}
                        <li>
                            <a data-transition="" href="{{{link}}}">
                                <p>{{{title}}}</p>

<small>{{{count}}}</small>

                            </a>
                        </li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [Handlebars.js docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/):

> ## Handlebars Paths
>
> ...
>
> Nested handlebars paths can also include `../` segments, which evaluate their paths against a parent context.
>
> ...
>
> The `../` path segment references the parent template scope, not one level up in the context. This is because block helpers can invoke a block with any context, so the notion of "one level up" isn't particularly meaningful except as a reference to the parent template scope.

So `{{../count}}` or `{{../../count}}` might get you what you want. Hard to say without more context on how the `itemTemplate` is being used.